# Any application wherein i can create photo mosaic

Tags: software-recommendation

I am new to Ubuntu and  I wonder if there's an application that i can install so  I can create mosaic out of my photos.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend http://mosaically.com not just because it is mine ;) but it lets you create and share high-resolution zoomable photo mosaics online.

I realize it may not be "software that you install" strictly speaking as it's a web application, but it is an alternative that serves the same purpose.